# Vuejs Single File organization with Gulp

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I've followed the [laracast tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step/episodes/13) about Vue Workflow with Laravel.

So I have a main.js:

```
var Vue =require('vue');

import Tournament from '../components/Tournament.vue';
new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components: {Tournament},

    ready(){
        alert('Ready To Go');
    }

});
```

And then I have my Tournament.vue:

```
<template>
    I can't see this text on screen

</template>

<script>
    export default  {
        props: ['list'],

    }
</script>
```

And then, in my HTML, I have that:

```
<tournament></tournament>
<script src="/js/tournaments.js"></script>


/js/tournament.js is generated by gulp.
```

I can see the alert, so Vue works fine.

What I cant see is my template.

I never see the sentence:

```
     I can't see this text on screen
```

I also tried to display dynamic data with data(), but with no success.

Any idea what am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Vue = require('vue');
import Tournament from '../components/Tournament.vue'; 

new Vue({
    el: 'body', 
    components: {template: Tournament}, 
    ready() {
        alert('Ready To Go'); 
    }
});
```

Does that work??